# interpret the following C#.NET code related with RGB

Tags: c#, image-processing, rgb

this code is for **skin color segmentation** in C#.NET,please tell me what is **difference bet R & r** 

what tells the values of  **f_upper and f_lower** to us?

```
color = bm.GetPixel(i, j);
r = Convert.ToDouble(color.R) / Convert.ToDouble(color.R + color.G + color.B);
g = Convert.ToDouble(color.G) / Convert.ToDouble(color.R + color.G + color.B);
f_upper = -1.3767 * r * r + 1.0743 * r + 0.1452;
f_lower = -0.776 * r * r + 0.5601 * r + 0.1766;
```

Comment: r is a variable of type double that holds the result of the right hand portion of the expression.  R is a property of `color`.

Comment: U r correct ,but i want the meaning in the context of image proccesing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r` is a variable declared previously and is of type double (if the code isn't wrong it have to be declared in that way). While `R` is a property of the Color struct, which indicates the color *Red*.

For more info on RGB color model [look here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=upper=%20-1.3767%20%2a%20r%20%2a%20r%20%2b%201.0743%20%2a%20r%20%2b%200.1452), while for Color struct [look here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f_lower%20=%20-0.776%20%2a%20r%20%2a%20r%20%2b%200.5601%20%2a%20r%20%2b%200.1766&dataset=).

More specifically `r` is normalized value between 0 and 1 - % of R(Red color) in the color.
[f_upper](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=upper=%20-1.3767%20%2a%20r%20%2a%20r%20%2b%201.0743%20%2a%20r%20%2b%200.1452) and [f_lower](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f_lower%20=%20-0.776%20%2a%20r%20%2a%20r%20%2b%200.5601%20%2a%20r%20%2b%200.1766&dataset=) is not clear for me

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by normalized?  Just curious.

Comment: Normalized value is a value that establishes a relationship between part and whole. It's means value of R if R+G+B are the unit of measurement.

Comment: @Tim For example the *dot* product is calculated to find the angle between two normalized vectors. And it's calculated because as you know cos and sin can assume values from -1 to 1. (now the name **unit** vector says everything)